# Special symbol character in iOS navigation bar

Tags: ios, swift, button

How to type or implement "back" in iOS navigation bar as this image:

[image]

I understand if I put an image in a button, but what if I want to type the special symbol "<" and then append the Setting.
I tried a few special "back" character, but either the symbol is too small, or not looks like this.

[image]
If I set it as this in the property attribute, the button will like this:

[image]

How to resolve this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you doing this manually? Getting the back arrow is standard functionality of a navigation controller if you use it correctly.

Comment: Have you considered to change the title of backBarButtonItem? It would leave the arrow and change the title instead.

Comment: @rmaddy I know what you mean, but in this case, this view controller is transmitted programatically, not by the storyboard. Any ideas how to do it programatically?

Comment: You don't need a storyboard to create and use a navigation controller.

Comment: @rmaddy would you mind teach me how to get the back arrow as standard functionality of a navigation controller?

Comment: Push two or more view controllers onto the nav controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Swift 3.0 StoryBoard

You can try this

[image: Add Back Button title in NavigationItem like this]

And you can get result

[image: result]